# Is the Salesforce Package Installer customizable?

Tags: package, app, package-install

In salesforce when you install an application  from the app exchange, it brings you to the Package Installer, a three step process which allows the person installing the package to  approve package API access, choose a security level, and lastly Install the package.
It looks like this: 
[image: Package Installer]

I was wondering if there is anyway to customize this process.  I would like to have a visual force page or two that allow the user to select certain components to install, and I wasn't sure if this was possible either through this Package Installer, or another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. You can set an [InstallHandler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_install_handler.htm) to create data, deploy a metadata file, etc. Generally, though, any other actions you will want to take should be either (a) documented in a post-installation doc, or (b) set up as a Visualforce page that the administrator should visit after installation. You may want to submit this as an idea on the [IdeaExchange](http://ideas.salesforce.com/).

Comment: Thank you.  I probably will submit an idea if somebody hasent already.  I feel like this could definitely help cut down on the amount of programming intensive post-install-docs.

Comment: @LShropshire I agree. I'm kind of surprised this isn't already a feature in and of itself, much less a current idea (I did a brief search before posting this answer).